# Extract colon separated values from string

Tags: go

I have a Go variable of type `string`, when I do `fmt.Println(variable)` my terminal prints out
`{"access_key":"AAAAAA","secret_key":"XXXXXXX"}`
. How do I extract the values "AAAAAA" and "XXXXXXX"?

Comment: Use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of working code

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Somestruct struct {
    AccessKey string `json:"access_key"`
    SecretKey string `json:"secret_key"`
}

func main() {

    var output Somestruct

    S := `{"access_key":"AAAAAA","secret_key":"XXXXXXX"}`

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(S), &output)

    fmt.Println(output.SecretKey)

}
```

See https://play.golang.org/p/vaPVHmo8fhR

I suggested that you learn how to work with json and structs in go.

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/